# xfs_repair could not find valid secondary superblock

Tags: centos, xfs

I had 3 bad tracks on my hard drive so I used Disk Genius to fix it,ofcourse the data near the back tracks were wiped out.Then I booted from linux rescue disk and run

```
xfs_repair /dev/sda1
xfs_repair /dev/sda2
```

sda1 went through ok but sda2 at some point it says"Sorry,could not find valid secondary superblock" and can't go all the way through.What other method do I have to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When you have hard drive errors, it's always better to have the following:

- a bootable USB running the same OS you're running
- a hard drive equal to or larger than the hard drive you're recovering from
- a hard drive to save your valuable data on

Then you should immediately create a copy of your failing hard drive using `ddrescue` onto the new one and work from the copy so you can always go back and try again...

Now that you didn't, you can't any more *but I still would take an image at this point in time*, because no superblocks at all means that (most of) your data is still there, it just cannot be found and you can still use:

- [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)
- [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)
- [foremost](https://linux.die.net/man/1/foremost)

to recover individual files.